# How to change third column of a variable so it is encased with single quotation marks using AWK or SED

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a variable $out:

```
out=1,2,3,4,5
```

I want to change the third column so the value gets single quotation marks as in (I talk of columns here as $out represents the values of an insert statement for a database entry):

```
out=1,2,'3',4,5
```

Does anyone know how this could be done using awk or sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:

```
out=1,2,3,4,5
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -E "s/[^,]+/'&'/3" <<<"$out"
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ $3 = q $3 q }1' FS=, OFS=, q="'" <<<"$out"
```

Output in both cases:

```
1,2,'3',4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash only...

```
$ out=1,2,3,4,5

$ echo $out | ( IFS=',' read a b c d e ; echo $a $b $c $d $e )
1 2 3 4 5

$ echo $out | ( IFS=',' read a b c d e ; echo "$a,$b,'$c',$d,$e" )
1,2,'3',4,5

$ out="$(echo $out | ( IFS=',' read a b c d e ; echo "$a,$b,'$c',$d,$e" ))"

$ echo $out
1,2,'3',4,5

$
```

Related information: [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) -> Bash guides